# Want to compare current location with the location stored in sqlite?

Tags: android

I want to change my profile mode based on location. My longitude and latitude is stored in database.Database is work properly but scheduling is not done. Service class can be use to done the background tasks I use it, but I don't know how to compare current longitude and latitude with the latitude and longitude stored in sqlite database in the form of string.

Comment: define `compare location` term. some code with your attempts to solve the problem would definitely help

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want say...?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to compare two values?

Comment: Well, Latitude and Longitude are of type double. You can directly compare it using == operator including and operator in between. Do not kill me if misunderstood your question.

Comment: and again, if you change profile based on your location, your profile will not last long as GPS is quite precise with coordinates and as you move, your profile will change again and again

Comment: I want to know how to compare current value with the value stored in sqlite database

Comment: what would be a result of such comparison?

Comment: Latitude and longitude was stored in database in the form of String, Now in my service class I write a code to get current latitude and longitude and change them into string. Now I want to compare both Strings.